# "Error: Not all code paths return a value."

Tags: c#, for-loop, return, return-value

My code, upon compilation, throws the titular exception. I don't understand why this happens because after extensive searching the reason the error occurs is seemingly only when conditions exist where there is no exit return statement, and yet I think my code is fully inclusive.

```
bool CheckExisting()
{
    Account loginAcc = new Account();

    string path = Application.StartupPath.ToString() + "\\Customers";
    int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
    for(int i = 0;i<fCount;i++)
    {
        String[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + "\\Customers\\");
        XmlDocument xmlFile =new XmlDocument();
        xmlFile.Load(filePaths[i]);

        foreach(XmlNode node in xmlFile.SelectNodes("//Account"))
        {
            string firstName = node.SelectSingleNode("FirstName").InnerText;
            string lastName = node.SelectSingleNode("LastName").InnerText;
            string address1 = node.SelectSingleNode("Address1").InnerText;
            string address2 = node.SelectSingleNode("Address2").InnerText;
            string postCode = node.SelectSingleNode("Postcode").InnerText;
             string telePhone = node.SelectSingleNode("Telephone").InnerText;
            string mobile = node.SelectSingleNode("Mobile").InnerText;

            Account newAcc = new Account();

            newAcc.firstName = firstName;
            newAcc.lastName = lastName;
            newAcc.address1 = address1;
            newAcc.address2 = address2;
            newAcc.postCode = postCode;
            newAcc.telephone = telePhone;
            newAcc.mobile = mobile;

            loginAcc = newAcc;
        }

        if(txtFirstName.Text == loginAcc.firstName && txtLastName.Text == loginAcc.lastName)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need another `return` outside of your `for` loop if I count your brackets properly. Like; `return false; } return false;` at the end.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to read your code if you'd fix the indentation.

Comment: @SonerGönül You do. There is no guarantee that `fCount` is != 0 after `Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length`.

Comment: My guess is, you meant the final `return false` to be outside the scope of the outer-most loop.

Comment: Lots of the comments were right and it was that I'd put my last `return false;` one set of parenthesis early. Doh! Sorry about the silly error, but thank you, everyone!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is effectively:

```
bool CheckExisting()
{
    // Some setup code

    for (int i = 0; i < fCount; i++)
    {
        // Code which isn't terribly relevant
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Now the C# 5 language specification section 8.8.3 talks about the reachability of the end of a `for` statement:

> The end point of a `for` statement is reachable if at least one of the following is true:
>
> - The `for` statement contains a reachable `break` statement that exits the `for` statement.
> - The `for` statement is reachable and a *for-condition* is present and does not have the constant value `true`.

The latter is true in this case, so the end of the `for` statement is reachable... and that's the end of the method. The end of a method with a non-void return type can never be reachable.

Note that this is the case even if a *human* could detect that you can never reach the end of the for statement. For example:

```
bool Broken()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        return true;
    }
    // This is still reachable!
}
```

*We* know that the loop will always execute at least once, but the language rules don't - therefore the end of the statement is reachable, and you get a compile-time error.

Comment: Checking this as the answer, because of the most in depth answer. Its good to hear some of the rules C runs by. The last code snippet was very easy to understand, as well. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why the compiler/language does only allow a constant value of `true` and not constant numeric values like in your last sample. It would be easy to analyse that the loop is entered and not so hard to see that the `return` statement is reachable under every case.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Hmmm... with my "not quite a language designer, but a language standard reviewer" hat on, I suspect it would make the language specification *much* more complex. "Constant value of true" is pretty straightforward - "value which must evaluate to true on the initial iteration because of the following rules" becomes much harder - and is never likely to be enough to satisfy everyone.

Comment: @JonSkeet: you could use a formulation that is understandable and corrrect at the same time like "a for-condition is present and can not be evaluated to true at compile time". If someone doesn't understand the "compile time" part, he will be reminded with an error.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: The language specification needs to be precise about what that means though - otherwise you could have code that will compile with one compiler but not with another, and that's a problem. (We have that in a few places already, and I wouldn't want there to be more.)

Answer (score 3):

If `fCount` were to be 0 then your loop would not execute and you'll not hit any of the return statements.

Some condensing and improved indentation makes it clear:

```
    int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
    for(int i = 0;i<fCount;i++){

        ...

        if(txtFirstName.Text == loginAcc.firstName && txtLastName.Text == loginAcc.lastName){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Possibly in the "real world" fCount can never be 0, however compiler/runtime won't know this.

Answer (score 2):

That happened because **after for loop you have returned Nothing.**

When your method executes it is expected to return the type you defined.  When the code execution path goes into your for statement, it is fine because it returns. If the code does NOT go into the for loop, that your code does not return anything. ***That is the error. `Run time` exception likely .Walk through the code with pencil and paper and see how it executes***

Answer (score 1):

You missed a return. This should work.

```
bool CheckExisting()
{
        Account loginAcc = new Account();

        string path = Application.StartupPath.ToString() + "\\Customers";
        int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;

        for(int i = 0;i<fCount;i++)
        {
            String[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + "\\Customers\\");
            XmlDocument xmlFile =new XmlDocument();
            xmlFile.Load(filePaths[i]);

            foreach(XmlNode node in xmlFile.SelectNodes("//Account"))
            {
                string firstName = node.SelectSingleNode("FirstName").InnerText;
                string lastName = node.SelectSingleNode("LastName").InnerText;
                string address1 = node.SelectSingleNode("Address1").InnerText;
                string address2 = node.SelectSingleNode("Address2").InnerText;
                string postCode = node.SelectSingleNode("Postcode").InnerText;
                string telePhone = node.SelectSingleNode("Telephone").InnerText;
                string mobile = node.SelectSingleNode("Mobile").InnerText;

                Account newAcc = new Account();

                newAcc.firstName = firstName;
                newAcc.lastName = lastName;
                newAcc.address1 = address1;
                newAcc.address2 = address2;
                newAcc.postCode = postCode;
                newAcc.telephone = telePhone;
                newAcc.mobile = mobile;

                loginAcc = newAcc;
            }


            if(txtFirstName.Text == loginAcc.firstName && txtLastName.Text == loginAcc.lastName)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return  false;
            } 
        return false;       
        }

      return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to do this: (I'm stealing [CodeCaster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27381720/5409)'s cleaned up version)

```
bool CheckExisting()
{
    //
    for(/**/)
    {
        //
        foreach(/**/)
        {
            //
        }

        if(/**/)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        // return false; NOT HERE, because it's not reachable in the first place.
    }
    return false; // BUT HERE, in case fCount = 0
}
```

Also, you could do away with the if-else at the end and just do

```
return txtFirstName.Text == loginAcc.firstName && txtLastName.Text == loginAcc.lastName;
```

... since that's a boolean expression already.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool CheckExisting(){
    Account loginAcc = new Account();

    string path = Application.StartupPath.ToString() + "\\Customers";
    int fCount = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length;
    for(int i = 0;i<fCount;i++){
        String[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Application.StartupPath + "\\Customers\\");
        XmlDocument xmlFile =new XmlDocument();
        xmlFile.Load(filePaths[i]);

        foreach(XmlNode node in xmlFile.SelectNodes("//Account")){
            string firstName = node.SelectSingleNode("FirstName").InnerText;
            string lastName = node.SelectSingleNode("LastName").InnerText;
            string address1 = node.SelectSingleNode("Address1").InnerText;
            string address2 = node.SelectSingleNode("Address2").InnerText;
            string postCode = node.SelectSingleNode("Postcode").InnerText;
            string telePhone = node.SelectSingleNode("Telephone").InnerText;
            string mobile = node.SelectSingleNode("Mobile").InnerText;

            Account newAcc = new Account();

            newAcc.firstName = firstName;
            newAcc.lastName = lastName;
            newAcc.address1 = address1;
            newAcc.address2 = address2;
            newAcc.postCode = postCode;
            newAcc.telephone = telePhone;
            newAcc.mobile = mobile;

            loginAcc = newAcc;
        }


        if(txtFirstName.Text == loginAcc.firstName && txtLastName.Text == loginAcc.lastName){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    return false;
    }
??????
}
```

not returning anything if you are not entering into the for loop. 
or you are not returning anything if your "FCount" is "0".

Answer (score 1):

To put it simply, just add a default `return false` at the end. Here's your code snippet:

```
        if(txtFirstName.Text == loginAcc.firstName && txtLastName.Text == loginAcc.lastName)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
        return false;
}
```

Just think about the case scenario where `fCount` is zero or less than it.

```
for(int i = 0;i<fCount;i++)
```

The for loop will be skipped. So where's the return statement for that? That's why the compiler is throwing this error.