# Calculate the stratified value of n+nn+nnn

Tags: c#

I tried to Write a console application that take a integer number from client and check if this number can be stratified, i.e. can be represented as

```
number = d + dd + ddd + ... + dd...ddd
```

where d is some digit. For instance

```
36 = 3 + 33
861 = 7 + 77 + 777
335 - can't be represent in d + dd + ddd
```

This is what Ido but I have an error “not all code path return a value”

```
using System;

namespace nn
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        }

        public static int N()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Input integer");
            //ask user to input integer
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int d = 1; d <= 9; d++)
            {
                var s = d;
                var c = d;
                while (s < n)
                {
                    c = 10 * c + d; // generates dd, ddd, ...
                    s += c;
                }
                if (s == n)
                {
                    return d;
                }
                else
                {

                    return -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Please use "speaking" variable names. "s", "d", "c"  are in general bad choices (whith exceptions).

Comment: 2. Since you `return` in both branches of the `if`, the for loop will only ever run for `d = 1`.

Comment: 3. Since you do not _call_ `N()`, this Program das nothing at all.

Comment: I guess the compiler does not analyze that `d=1; d<=9` is true at least once, so that the `for` loop is definitly entered. In theory, the loop could _not_ be entered, and then your method does not return an int as expected. Add an `return 0;` after the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

As error is self explanatory, Return type of function `N()` is `int` and your code is not returning integer after the `for` loop. To solve this issue, return integer after the closing bracket of for loop,

```
 public static int N()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Input integer");
        //ask user to input integer
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int d = 1; d <= 9; d++)
        {
            var s = d;
            var c = d;
            while (s < n)
            {
                c = 10 * c + d; // generates dd, ddd, ...
                s += c;
            }
            if (s == n)
            {
                return d;
            }
            else
            {

                return -1;
            }
        }
        return -1;   //This is missing return statement.
    }
```

Comment: Until now I'd actually expect that the compiler knows that the `for` loop is at least entered once and then will definitly return. It seems it does not.

Comment: @RenéVogt: could be that `d` is modifed in the for-loop at runtime. Also possible that  a `continue` or `break` skips that `if...else`. Well, the compiler simply doesn't do that analysis.

Comment: @RenéVogt `for` will be changed to `while` by the compiler, so it should be able to detect that it shall be entered at least once, I would recon. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Yeah, I also realized after your comment, that we need to explicitly return something after for loop even initialization `d` is done before condition

Comment: This is covered in Jon's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27381774/284240
The language just allows the constant value `true` as condition. Otherwise it will be assumed that the for-loop can be left so you need a return statement afterwards.